# Nginx + Docker. 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I've been struggling for a bit on this and I'm starting to get depressed...

I'm running a droplet on DigitalOcean with **Ubuntu 18.10.**

I've used **Docker** to serve my different service (nuxt, socket.io, nginx, nodejs)

And I've used **Nginx** to revese proxy those services (at first i'd just want to render the nuxt app)

When executing

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

All processes are running and are **accessible on the server** but **inaccessible from my local machine** (I get a 504 Gateway Timeout).

There is one time where I got it working but when adding some location rule, it broke again.

So here's my config for **nginx** :

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name 104.248.201.255;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://doodlehelha-nuxt:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

And here's the nginx service in my *docker-compose.yml*

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15
    container_name: doodlehelha-nginx
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '443:443'
    expose:
        - '8080'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - nuxt
      - api
      - socket
```

This is a very simple configuration and that's why I don't know what's wrong...
If someone more experienced can point it out, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: If instead you proxypass to `proxy_pass http://nuxt:3000;` is it working?

Comment: Same error. Is it weird ?

Comment: post full `docker-compose.yml` config...

Comment: Here it is 
https://gist.github.com/KiritchoukC/32fdd74dfb1df5dbfcf90b4522ba4f1f#file-docker-compose-yml